# Spotify iOS SDK login with access token from django-allauth

Tags: swift, django, api, oauth-2.0, spotify

I am creating an iOS app with Spotify playback with a django backend. This is my first programming project, and I am a little hung up on oauth2. I know that I need to do the authorization code flow on the server side to obtain refreshable user tokens.

I set up django-allauth on my django project, and managed to get it working to authenticate Spotify users despite the limited documentation for Spotify. I can call localhost:8000/users/spotify/login and the code will be refreshed and a vlid access token is stored in the database (made authorized request on Postman). I believe this will work when I deploy the changes to heroku as well, I just have not yet.

Getting back to my iOS app, I am trying to use the sdk to stream songs. I start the SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance() with my client ID, no problem, and then try to login with access token hard coded, with no success. I know that I am missing something, probably involving the session that is returned when authentication is handled completely through iOS. I am hoping for clarification on how to complete this implementation and log in on the SDK properly using the access tokens stored in my django backend. This is the function that attempts to set up spotify and login. It is called in the app delegate.

```
        print("Setting up spotify")
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().clientID = "hardcodedclientID"
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().redirectURL = URL(string: "hardcodedredirectURL")
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().sessionUserDefaultsKey = "spotifySessionKey"

    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope, SPTAuthUserLibraryReadScope]

    do {
        try SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().start(withClientId: "hardcodedclientID")
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't start Spotify SDK")
    }
    print("shared instance started")
    SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().login(withAccessToken: hardCodedAccessTokenFromDjango)
    print(SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().loggedIn)
```

I have set up all the app settings I need to, per the two tutorials I followed [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios-sdk/quick-start/) and [here.](https://medium.com/@brianhans/getting-started-with-the-spotify-ios-sdk-435607216ecc) I know that I will not be able to hard code the information like that, but I was under the impression that I should be able to login(withaccesstoken:) simply using the access token I had. I am trying to find the best practice for sending my acces token through My Django REST API and then authenticating the SDK with it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to get the same code to work. I added a session variable and set it, but the main problem was that django-allauth defaulted to requesting no scopes, I changed the source code to the scopes I needed and the process went much smoother. I believe I can access my access token through my api and that will be enough to initialize everythign client side, which is wa